# High Voltage, High Current, Bipolar (4 Wires) Stepper Motor Control

Tags: stepper-motor

I am new here, and I'm new to Arduino. I am making an attempt to control a high voltage (~48V), high current (~6A), bipolar (4 Wires) stepper motor.

I understand how to drive a stepper motor, and I have found the bipolar schematics on the Arduino library, but none of the solutions handle a motor this big.  Most drivers use the SN754410 or L293 from what I've seen.  I have also noticed stacking of the SN754410 chips for higher current ratings, but I suppose I would need 6 of them, and they still will not handle 48V.

Would I have to build my own dual h-bridge from NPN Transistors or [MOSFETS](https://famaga.ch/catalog/behlke/order-109737)?  Does anyone have an example circuit that has some protective features, such as the back current diodes.  Would this be enough protection to avoid damage to the Arduino?  I would also like to keep this relatively cost efficient.

Thanks in advance!  I hope I made everything clear.

Comment: Take a look at [DRV8711](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8711.pdf). Also in your question were your referencing [HTS 181-01-C](https://www.behlke.com/pdf/181-01-c.pdf)

Comment: Can you please share the stepper Motor Specifications?